# How to redirect after certain path ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call to a controller action called ExportToExcel. ExportToExcel builds a url and return it in json to front-end, which calls another controller action on ajax success.

The below code works locally but not on dev.
The path locally consists of basepath only (e.g. http://localhost:portNumber/controllerName/actionName), while on dev, there's a path after base path, then controller name and action gets appended (e.g. dev/appName/controllerName/actionName)

How to append downloadExcelUrl to dev/appName instead of dev/appName ?

Ajax call to Action One in controller

```
     $("#exportToExcel").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Test")',
                success: function (result) {
                    window.location.href = result.redirectUrl;
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    console.log("Error in ajax call to ExportToExcel: " + xhr.status + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

    });
```

Action One in controller, that builds url to Action Two
      public JsonResult ExportToExcel()
        {
            try
            {
                //some code

```
            string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                Session[handle] = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }


            var urlBuilder = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
            var downloadExcelUrl = urlBuilder.Action("DownloadExcel", "Test", new { fileGuid = handle, fileName = "Excel_Form.xlsx" });
            return Json(new { status = "success", redirectUrl = downloadExcelUrl }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json("Exception thrown in ExportToExcel", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Action Two in controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult DownloadExcel(string fileGuid, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session[fileGuid] != null)
            {
                byte[] data = Session[fileGuid] as byte[];
                return File(data, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                return new EmptyResult();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

Locally:

http://localhost:51865/Test/ExportToExcel?_=1562712387404

http://localhost:51865/Test/DownloadExcel?fileGuid=00b2bca3-e323-45e4-97a8-4cdcc78eb445&fileName=Excel_Form.xlsx

on Dev:

http://dev/appName/Test/Process/undefined

Comment: Can you clarify the correct URL you get locally vs. the incorrect URL you get from Dev? For instance, you say "...to dev/appName instead of dev/appName". It's not clear to me what needs to change.

Comment: Can you post what urlBuilder.Action(..) returned for the URL to download the XML file?

Comment: @jefftrotman I updated my question. please tell me if i have to explain more

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I just forgot to copy the rebuilt dll of the project to dev. Missing step in deployment. My bad. It's working now

Comment: @BrianMains thank you man it works